# I can't install Flash on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, flash

I'm installing Lubuntu 13.04 (updated really) and I'm having trouble installing Flash.  I had trouble with the previous version too.  I managed by doing all the updates I possibly could find!  Well now I'm completely updated.  I saw some directions  for a couple of commands to enter at a terminal, but it told me that I don't have the rights, can't unlock a folder.  I'm the only one on my netbook.

Any and all help is most appreciated.  I'm terribly sorry if I didn't follow some procedure on asking.

Comment: I bet you forgot to add `sudo` at the start. `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`

Answer (score 2):

To install Adobe Flash Player in Ubuntu 13.04,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: That was pretty f-ing easy!  The directions I saw had the thing on the Terminal but the command wasn't this easy.  Looks like Flash is working for me now.  Thanks for your help.