# Installing Flash Player

Tags: flash

I have downloaded Adobe Flash player 11.2, but can't install it.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Can anyone help me?

I don't know which program it will open with.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329788/i-cant-install-flash-on-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you also would like to uncomment the line

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

in */etc/apt/sources.list* and install the graphical adobe configuration tool for flash:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin
```

BTW: you can get it for your kde settings too: **adobe-flash-properties-kde**

Comment: OK for 13.04, BTW adobe-flash-properties-gtk is not present in the new Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)?. It comes with inbuilt flash player.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/)
2. Click on Flash Player link on the bottom-right corner of the web page.
3. Select the option Apt for Ubuntu 10.04+ and click on Download.
4. Authenticate using the root password and you will see that the cache is updated automatically.
5. Once this is done, you will see a dialog box, prompting you to install flash plug-in. Hit install, and you're done!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras flashplugin-installer
```